# Get missing frame number in ffmpeg decoder

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

When using ffmpeg for decoding.it skips some frames and didn't decode them.
I want to get the missing frame number as they are in original file.

Comment: It seems ffmpeg does not return `I` frames. Thus if for instance, you obtain motion vectors, it will skip these `I` frames during the decoding.